# Put largest value timestamp in array in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe (say `df1`) with the following columns

1.> `category` - contains unique category types

2.> `start_time_array` - array of timestamps in ascending order

3.> `end_time_array` - array of timestamps in ascending order

4.> `lenStart` - length of arrays in `start_time_array`

5.> `lenEnd` - length of arrays in `end_time_array`

Following is an example of `df1`:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+------+
|category|                            end_time_array|                          start_time_array|lenStart|lenEnd|
+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+------+
|       A|[2017-01-18 00:00:00, 2017-01-27 00:00:00]|[2017-01-16 00:00:00, 2017-01-25 00:00:00]|       2|     2|
|       B|                     [2017-02-18 00:00:00]|[2017-02-14 00:00:00, 2017-02-21 00:00:00]|       2|     1|
+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+------+
```

There is another dataframe `df2` which contains two columns `category` and `timestamp`. `df2` contains the same values of `category` as `df1` and the values of timestamps inside arrays in `df1` are a subset of the timestamps in `df2`. Following is an example of `df2`

```
+--------+-------------------+
|category|          timestamp|
+--------+-------------------+
|       A|2017-01-16 00:00:00|
|       A|2017-01-18 00:00:00|
|       A|2017-01-25 00:00:00|
|       A|2017-01-27 00:00:00|
|       B|2017-02-14 00:00:00|
|       B|2017-02-18 00:00:00|
|       B|2017-02-21 00:00:00|
|       B|2017-02-22 00:00:00|
|       B|2017-02-24 00:00:00|
|       B|2017-02-25 00:00:00|
+--------+-------------------+
```

As we see in the above example in `df1`, for `category -> B` , `lenStart=2` is not equal to `lenEnd=1`. In all rows of `df1` , either `lenStart = lenEnd` , or , `lenStart = lenEnd+1`  **For all rows in `df1` where `lenStart = lenEnd+1`, I want to take the largest value of `timestamp` (of appropriate `category`) and place it in the array in `end_time_array`. How can I do this?**

Following is the expected output after processing of `df1` using information from `df2`

```
+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+------+
|category|                            end_time_array|                          start_time_array|lenStart|lenEnd|
+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+------+
|       A|[2017-01-18 00:00:00, 2017-01-27 00:00:00]|[2017-01-16 00:00:00, 2017-01-25 00:00:00]|       2|     2|
|       B|[2017-02-18 00:00:00, 2017-02-25 00:00:00]|[2017-02-14 00:00:00, 2017-02-21 00:00:00]|       2|     2|
+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on Spark 1.5+:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df3 = df1.where(F.col('lenStart') == (F.col('lenEnd') + 1)).select('category')
df4 = df2.join(df3, 'Category').groupby('Category').agg(F.max('timestamp').alias('max'))
df5 = df1.join(df4, 'Category', 'left')
df1_changed = df5.withColumn('end_time_array', F.when(F.col('max').isNull(),
    F.col('end_time_array')).otherwise(F.concat(F.col('end_time_array'),
                                                F.array(F.col('max')))))
df1_changed = df1_changed.withColumn('lenEnd', F.size(F.col('end_time_array')))
```

`df1_changed` will have a modified `end_time_array` column with the wanted value added to it when the condition you requested applies, otherwise, it remains unchanged.